# Kotlin draw linear gradient relative to shape

Tags: android, kotlin, linear-gradients

I have a `Paint` object that contains a linear gradient like this:

```
init{
    this.myPaint.shader = LinearGradient(0f, 0f, 0f, 15f, 0xFF1F9928.toInt(), 0xFF184F1E.toInt(), Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
}
```

And i use it to draw a health bar for my character like this:

```
canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + 100f * fill, y + 15f, this.myPaint)
```

This work well. But when the character moves with the camera the gradient stays at its original place. This results in the health bar changing color based on its position.

How can i make the gradient stay fixed to the health bar, instead of the global coordinate system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

You have to translate the canvas, and draw your gradient at (0, 0) position. Then restore the canvas back.

```
canvas.save()
canvas.translate(x, y)
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 100f * fill, 15f, this.myPaint)
canvas.restore()
```

This is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Never used `LinearGradient` myself however from what I can tell from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient#LinearGradient(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20long[],%20float[],%20android.graphics.Shader.TileMode)). You will have to configure the shader every time you call `drawRect`. The gradient stays in the initial position because the gradient's coordinates never change.

Changes needed:

```
// pass appropriately the coordinates you want here
this.myPaint.shader = LinearGradient(0f, 0f, 0f, 15f, 0xFF1F9928.toInt(), 0xFF184F1E.toInt(), Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + 100f * fill, y + 15f, this.myPaint)
```

Be careful about creating object creation `onDraw`.

Comment: isn't it bad for performance to create objects inside draw/game loop each frame?

Comment: Yes, it could be bad. I would recommend you to profile it. I've edited my answer. However, the answer still points to correct direction as coordinates stay fixed, it's expected for the gradient to not change position.

Comment: I appreciate your correct response, But unfortunately i can not sacrifice performance. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I found the solution. I posted below